# Netstat listening programs on ports alternative on Debian 9

Tags: debian, netstat, stretch

What is the alternative to command `netstat -ntpl` on Debian 9?
I am using this command to check what program is listening on port.
Alternatively with parameters `-ntupl` (with u) including UDP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`netstat` (with both options) works fine on Debian 9. If it is not installed, it is in the package `net-tools`.

There is also the `ss` command (dumps socket statistics) from the package `iproute2`. The option you have given, seem all to be the same: `ss -nptl`, etc.. The output format is a bit different, though.

https://linux.die.net/man/8/ss
https://scottlinux.com/2012/08/16/ss-the-alternative-to-netstat/

Comment: I know, but net-tools are deprecated and i want to know what alternative can i use?

Comment: OK, then I misunderstood you. Will add `ss` to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `ss -a4n` for listening all ipv4 port (listening or not) and not resolve the port number (show the number, not the service)